# System.String[] returned instead of array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return an array of strings but `return test;` only gives "System.String[]" as output. If I iterate through test[] all values are filled in correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static String[] ReturnTheStrings()
 {
     FillTheArray();
     String[] test = new String[178];

     for (int i = 0; i < 178; i++)
     {
         if ((Class7.Method4(strings[i])) == "decoding wrong")
         {
             test[i] = strings[i+1];
             //System.Console.WriteLine("Non-encoded value");
         }
         else
         {
             test[i] = Class7.Method4(strings[i+1]);
             //System.Console.WriteLine("Encoded value");
         }
     }
     return test;
 }
```

I'm using MS Visual C# 2010.

Comment: Your code will fail with 'Index out of range' exception on the last loop.

Comment: It's worth noting that you are already returning a string array.  There is nothing wrong at all with how you're returning it.  Your error is in how it's used by whatever calls this method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Calling `.ToString()` on an array will return "System.String[]". If you want to display each value in the array, you have iterate over it.

For example:

```
foreach (var value in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Or, as @Oded pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146723/system-string-returned-instead-of-array#comment16250818_12146747), you can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, stringArray));
```