# webservice to retrive data from a database using C#

Tags: c#, web-services

**I have created a webservice to retrieve list of owners for a particular company code.
When i run this webservice ...it is working fine .
Kindly help to me to execute this with a web application as when i am doing the same the result shown is "SYSTEM.TOSTRING[]"
THE web application consists of a text box for input for company code and a button to fetch ownername in a dropdownlist

```
 public class OwnerWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{     
             string ConnectionString = "Data Source=localdb" + ";" + "Initial Catalog=Prod" + ";" +
             "Persist Security Info=True" + ";" +
             "User ID=User1" + ";" +
             "Password=User1" + ";" +
             "enlist=false";

 [WebMethod]
    public string[] dtFetch(string strCompanyCode)
    {
        List<string> messages = new List<string>();
        SqlConnection cnMySQL = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString );
        cnMySQL.Open();
        string sqlquery = string.Format("SELECT OwnerName FROM tbl_Owner WHERE CompanyCode='{0}'", strCompanyCode);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cnMySQL);
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            messages.Add(sqlReader.GetString(0));
        }


        cnMySQL.Close();
        return messages.ToArray();

    }
```

}

Comment: I think your proxy is not up to date.

Comment: Its repeat question, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146723/system-string-returned-instead-of-array

Answer (score 0):

do not return a string[]
instead try to return a comma separated string.

for returning a comma separated string modify the last line from

```
return messages.ToArray();
```

to

```
return String.Join(',',messages.ToArray());
```

also change the return type to `string`
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a collection of strings (string[]) into one single textbox, which can show only one string.

Your webservice is fine: it returns a collection of owner names. So the user interfacce has to be modified.

There are several solutions:

1. In your user interface, concatinate all strings into one string (String.Join(", ", messages)). Do not do this in your webservice! A webserivce should not be allowed to do UI-formatting!
2. In your user interface, replace the textbox by a listbox, show you can show multiple owner names in that listbox.

One last (off-topic) suggestion: using the keyword "using" for your SqlConnection and SqlDataReader. This ensures that they will be closed, even if an exception occurs.