# System.String[] returned instead of array value

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to write a very basic program to return the value of 2 elements in an array of string but the output is System.String[] instead of the actual value of the string. Is it because I have it two letters associated to 1 element. For example :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] a = new string[2] { "ugly string", "lovely string" };
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
```

It should return ugly string and lovely string in two separate lines. However it's just showing System.String[] in 2 different lines.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(item)`, not `Console.WriteLine(a)`

Comment: I don't think this is a typo, but rather a genuine lack of knowledge of the correct usage of control structures, even if it's trivial to fix. Voted to reopen.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146723/system-string-returned-instead-of-array

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your line

```cs
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

to

```cs
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

`foreach` will make sure the *for each* (hence the name) iteration through the list called `a` the current value will be put into the variable named `item`.

Comment: trying to learn the basics. Thank you. It worked.

Comment: @AkshayKhard think about what "a" and "item" represent in your code